# Is "The Suburbs" the sequel to "Funeral", both by Arcade Fire?

Tags: meaning, alternative-rock

The famous and successful *The Suburbs* by Arcade Fire won the Album of the Year by its eccentric alternative rock vibe. The album tells the story of a grown and metropolized person who thinks back of childhood life with purity, exploration, and even stupidity, in the suburban area; the album then goes on narrating about what has changed and how it has become much more modern but somewhat gloomy.

I've been listening to the album for years before deciding to listening to Arcade Fire's debut album, *Funeral*. Despite not understanding why the name is as it is, my other concern is bugging me more: is *The Suburbs* the sequel to *Funeral*?

*Funeral* is more about a kid in the quiet suburban neighborhood. The kid has good friends to escape to when bad things happen ("I'll dig a tunnel from my window to yours"), holds childish grudge against family member who leaves for bigger opportunity and to see more than life (*Laïka*), listens to stories of grandparents about their past (*Haiti*), thinks they're grown adult with responsibility but actually still a child soul (*Wake Up*), goes through town with dad observing from the backseat (*In the Backseat*), etc. Everything comes together to me like a storytelling melody by a kid that has so much to cling on to in their childhood.

Has the kid in *Funeral* grown up to become the adult in *The Suburbs*?

Answer (score 2):

According to sourced content in Wikipedia, both albums are semi-autobiographical, with the [earlier album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funeral_%28album%29) drawing from all band members' experiences, and the [later album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Suburbs_%28album%29) centering more closely on the experiences of brothers Win and Will Butler (both members of Arcade Fire).

So from that point of view, I think it's entirely fair to perceive continuity between the P.O.V. characters in both albums --not as part of a developed, ongoing fictional narrative, but as representing aspects of the actual songwriters' lives.